# PHP 3DES decrypt showed weird(bad) characters

Tags: php, encryption, utf-8, 3des, roundcube

I have a PHP form for which I have implemented 3des encryption/decryption. After submitting and inserting information into database from the front-end, I want to read out the information in the back-end.

After decryption my form's information instead of correct characters it just return some bad charater for me such as : `�СU�k�8��t�ó�2(�f�B`. How can I solve this issue?

Here is my source code:

```
   <?php
function encrypt($clear, $key , $base64 = true)
  {
    if (!$clear)
      return '';
    $clear = pack("a*H2", $clear, "80");

    if (function_exists('mcrypt_module_open') &&
        ($td = mcrypt_module_open(MCRYPT_TripleDES, "", MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, "")))
    {
      $iv = create_iv(mcrypt_enc_get_iv_size($td));
      mcrypt_generic_init($td, $key, $iv);
      $cipher = $iv . mcrypt_generic($td, $clear);
      mcrypt_generic_deinit($td);
      mcrypt_module_close($td);
    }
    else {
      @include_once('des.inc');

      if (function_exists('des')) {
        $des_iv_size = 8;
        $iv = create_iv($des_iv_size);
        $cipher = $iv . des($key, $clear, 1, 1, $iv);
      }
      else {
        raise_error(array(
          'code' => 500, 'type' => 'php',
          'file' => __FILE__, 'line' => __LINE__,
          'message' => "Could not perform encryption; make sure Mcrypt is installed or lib/des.inc is available"
        ), true, true);
      }
    }
    return $base64 ? base64_encode($cipher) : $cipher;

  }


function decrypt($cipher, $key , $base64 = true)
  {
    if (!$cipher)
      return '';

    $cipher = $base64 ? base64_decode($cipher) : $cipher;

    if (function_exists('mcrypt_module_open') &&
        ($td = mcrypt_module_open(MCRYPT_TripleDES, "", MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, "")))
    {
      $iv_size = mcrypt_enc_get_iv_size($td);
      $iv = substr($cipher, 0, $iv_size);

      // session corruption? (#1485970)
      if (strlen($iv) < $iv_size)
        return '';

      $cipher = substr($cipher, $iv_size);
      mcrypt_generic_init($td, $key, $iv);
      $clear = mdecrypt_generic($td, $cipher);
      mcrypt_generic_deinit($td);
      mcrypt_module_close($td);
    }
    else {
      @include_once('lib/des.inc');

      if (function_exists('des')) {
        $des_iv_size = 8;
        $iv = substr($cipher, 0, $des_iv_size);
        $cipher = substr($cipher, $des_iv_size);
        $clear = des($this->config->get_crypto_key($key), $cipher, 0, 1, $iv);
      }
      else {
        raise_error(array(
          'code' => 500, 'type' => 'php',
          'file' => __FILE__, 'line' => __LINE__,
          'message' => "Could not perform decryption; make sure Mcrypt is installed or lib/des.inc is available"
        ), true, true);
      }
    }

    /*-
     * Trim PHP's padding and the canary byte; see note in
     * rcmail::encrypt() and http://php.net/mcrypt_generic#68082
     */
    $clear = substr(rtrim($clear, "\0"), 0, -1);

    return $clear;
  }


function create_iv($size)
  {
    $iv = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $size; $i++)
        $iv .= chr(mt_rand(0, 255));
    return $iv;
  }

**echo decrypt('ijvdfvf1==+Ac44tgLHdAL+w7O2MiiIZplC','s&gs1?m5l8PQIOGckvxDT4kR',true);**

?>
```

I want to encrypt and decrypt UTF-8 characters in my form.

Comment: I barely know PHP but I it doesn't appear that you are undoing the initial `pack` operation in the decryptor. Maybe call `unpack` as the last step before returning.

Comment: @GregS , I could not understand your comment :( Where I have to unpack??????

Comment: Since you `pack` as the first step in `encrypt` you must `unpack` as the last step in `decrypt`.

Comment: @GregS, but I saw unpack has 2 arguments, one of them is my encrypted string but another one, what is it???????? please guide me more

Comment: As I said I barely know PHP. I'm merely observing that whatever you do in encryption you must undo in decryption.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have forgotten one `$cipher = substr($cipher, $des_iv_size);` in the mcrypt part of your `decrypt` function.

Furthermore you should explicitly convert strings to (and from) UTF-8 encoding if you want to support UTF-8.

Finally it seems you are using single DES if 3DES is not available. Is that on purpose?

Comment: Yes, I want to use DES